# How do I listen the event of Running IE with IWebBrowser2 in C++ XE2?

Tags: c++, c++builder, iwebbrowser2, c++builder-xe2

Currently I want to automate the running IE. I have successfully attached the running IE using below code (I assume there is only one IE within one tab)

```
#include "atl/atlbase.h"
#include <exdisp.h>
#include <mshtml.h>
CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> pCurIE;    
void __fastcall TForm4::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    bool SuccessToHook = false;
    CComPtr<IShellWindows> m_spSHWinds;
    if (FAILED(m_spSHWinds.CoCreateInstance( __uuidof( ShellWindows)))){

        return ;
    }


    LONG nCount;
    m_spSHWinds->get_Count( &nCount);
    ShowMessage(nCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++) {
        CComPtr<IDispatch> pDisp;
        m_spSHWinds->Item( CComVariant(i), &pDisp);
        CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2> pIE(pDisp);
        if (pIE == NULL){

            continue ;
        }
        CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispDoc;
        pIE->get_Document(&pDispDoc);
        CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pHtmlDoc(pDispDoc);
        if (pHtmlDoc){
            pCurIE = pIE;
            SuccessToHook = true;
            break ;
        }
    }
    ShowMessage(SuccessToHook ? "Success to hook." : "Failed to hook." );
}
```

Now I can control the current running IE like navigating and read the current state. But as I want to show messages when the events like onDocumentComplete Event are fired. I have no idea how to listen the event following my current code. A simple sample code with BCB will be very appreciated as there are some samples with VC++ but my project is on C++ XE2.

---

Thanks @Remy Lebeau and [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20060311022915/http://bdn.borland.com/article/0,1410,26734,00.html), I finally solve my problem.
I leave my code here and hope it maybe helpful for someone else.

A class derived from TEventDispatcher

```
#include <exdisp.h>
#include <exdispid.h>
#include <mshtml.h>
#include <mshtmdid.h>
#include <utilcls.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm4;
class EventHandler:public TEventDispatcher<EventHandler,&DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2>{
    private:
        bool connected;
        TForm4 *theform;
        IUnknown* server;
    protected:
        HRESULT InvokeEvent(DISPID id, TVariant *params){
            switch(id){
                case DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE:
                    ShowMessage("On Document Complete");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    public:
        EventHandler(){
            connected = false; //not connected;
            theform = false; //backptr to form is null
        }
        ~EventHandler(){
            if (connected)
                Disconnect();
        }
        void Connect(TForm4 *form,  IUnknown* srv){
            server = srv;
            theform = form; //back pointer to form to do stuff with it.
            server->AddRef(); //addref the server
            ConnectEvents(server);
        }
        void Disconnect(){
            DisconnectEvents(server);   //disconnect the events
            server->Release();
        }
};
```

Start to listen

```
void __fastcall TForm4::Button5Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Event = new EventHandler();
    Event->Connect(this, pCurIE);
}
```

Stop listening

```
void __fastcall TForm4::Button6Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Event->Disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write a class in your code that implements the `DWebBrowserEvents2` interface.  Then you can query the browser for its `IConnectionPointContainer` interface, call the `IConnectionPointContainer::FindConnectionPoint()` method to find the `IConnectionPoint` that cooresponds to `DWebBrowserEvents2`, and call the `IConnectionPoint::Advise()` method passing it an instance of your class.  Don't forget to call `IConnectionPoint::Unadvise()` when you are done using the events.

To help you with that, you can derive your class from the VCL's `TEventDispatcher` class in utilcls.h.  Its `ConnectEvents()` and `DisconnectEvents()` methods handle the `IConnectionPoint` stuff for you. You would then just override the abstract `InvokeEvent()` method (each of the browser's events have their own `DISPID` values).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I make a try first!

Comment: It works! You have answered me so many questions... Thank u very much!