# How to Get the Name of URL Opens in IE in my application at run time

Tags: c#

I wanted to get the name of the URL which user Opens in IE and wanted to save it to a File.I am ruuning a console application in which i wanted to get notify that new Url is open in IE and then Get that URL and save it to a File.Please Provide me some code snippet to do that .
Currently i am using this code which get the name of all URL opens but problem is that when i opens a new Url IN IE it doesnot get any new  URL in my Console application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in new ShellWindows())
        {

            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();

            if (filename == "iexplore")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ie.LocationURL);
                StreamWriter _objStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\file.txt", true);
                _objStreamWriter.WriteLine(ie.LocationURL);
                _objStreamWriter.Close();
            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: You want to listen to DWebBrowserEvents2 as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642964/how-do-i-listen-the-event-of-running-ie-with-iwebbrowser2-in-c-xe2).

Comment: Please provide any usefull linq do the same using c#.net .